Is there a way of tagging custom extraction models via the Azure Document Intelligence Studio UI?
Or even updating an existing model with tags via the FormRecognizer or DocumentIntelligence SDKs?
I noticed that the Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis.DocumentModelSummary exposes a Tags collection which would be super useful for filtering my models so this is what I'm trying to set, however I don't see any way of tagging the models to begin with.
I've hunted around numerous versions of both the FormRecognizer or DocumentIntelligence SDKs, and spent a lot of time googling to no avail.


however I don't see any way of tagging the models to begin with.

The DocumentModelSummary class indeed exposes the Tags property, allowing developers to manage tags associated with a document model.

Initialize a FormRecognizerClient object.
Retrieve the existing model summary using the GetModelSummaryAsync method.
Update the Tags property of the model summary with the desired tags. The tags are represented as a dictionary where the key is the tag name, and the value is a ModelTag object.
Call the UpdateModelAsync method to apply the changes to the model.

Code:
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new FormRecognizerClient
        var client = new FormRecognizerClient(new Uri("<YOUR_ENDPOINT>"), new AzureKeyCredential("<YOUR_API_KEY>"));

        // Get the existing model summary
        var modelSummary = await client.GetModelSummaryAsync("<MODEL_ID>");

        // Update the tags
        modelSummary.Value.Tags = new Dictionary<string, ModelTag>
        {
            { "InvoiceNumber", new ModelTag("InvoiceNumber") },
            { "Date", new ModelTag("Date") },
            { "TotalAmountDue", new ModelTag("TotalAmountDue") }
        };

        // Update the model
        await client.UpdateModelAsync("<MODEL_ID>", modelSummary.Value);
    }
}

Reference:

Way Tagging and Custom Extraction Models in Azure Document Intelligence Studio UI and SDKs


Legend. This looks like the way to go, but just to confirm - there's no way of doing this via the studio UI? Was hoping to get non-developers tagging models for me.

Yeah @Owen, Since there's no way to do this via studio UI.. If the update comes I will attach to this answer.

Which version of the Azure SDK are you using here? Because GetModelSummaryAsync() and UpdateModelAsync() are not available in the latest Azure.AI.FormRecognizer package (v4.1.0): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.formrecognizerclient?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-legacy. The links in the blog post all 404 as well.

As per the above document referred, He is using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer package (v4.1.0) and let me try as well.
